# Is there any way to find the base type of object for which the synonym is created in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, synonym

```
 CREATE SYNONYM office
   FOR SEQ001;
```

I need some system table/any other way that gives me information that `SEQ001` is sequence .

In short I need a query that enlist synonyms only created for synonym objects and no other objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be something like this:

```
SQL> create sequence seq001;

Sequence created.

SQL> create synonym syn_se for seq001;

Synonym created.

SQL> select s.synonym_name, o.object_name, o.object_type
  2  from user_synonyms s join user_objects o on o.object_name = s.table_name;

SYNONYM_NAME    OBJECT_NAME     OBJECT_TYPE
--------------- --------------- -------------------
SYN_SE          SEQ001          SEQUENCE

SQL>
```

Now, you can apply different filters to it, e.g. `where o.object_type = 'SEQUENCE'` to see only synonyms related to sequences.

Answer (score 0):

To list all synonyms that reference other synonyms use the dictionary view `ALL_SYNONYMS` and check if the synonym definition correspond to an other synonym.

**Example**

The first synonym reference a sequence, the two other reference a synonym.
The query shows the two "nested" synonyms.

```
create sequence seq001;
create synonym syn001 for seq001;
create synonym syn002 for syn001;
create synonym syn003 for syn002;

select OWNER, SYNONYM_NAME
from all_synonyms
where (TABLE_OWNER, TABLE_NAME) in 
(select OWNER, SYNONYM_NAME from all_synonyms)
;

OWNER      SYNONYM_NAME
---------- ------------
OOO        SYN002      
OOO        SYN003
```

The view `ALL_SYNONYMS` shows all synonyms that your user has a granted access. There is also a dictionary view `DBA_SYNONYMS` showing all *existing* synonyms, but you'll need extra privilege to access it.